# Grid not binding in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

This is probably a very simple thing, but I can't figure it out..

Clicking the 'find' button in this link:
https://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net/spa1/#/invoices
invokes the searchItems function properly.

For some reason clicking the 'find' button here doesn't invoke that same function:
https://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net/spa1/#/clients

The logic is pretty much duplicated.. your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had duplicate route defined both in route.js and in the module definition.